# mongodb #c driver aggregate: How to implement it in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

Good morning,

I have a collection with a huge number of documents, and what I want to do is group by a certain field and put the results into a new collection.

I know how to do this in MongoDB, and it works perfect:

```
db.collection_1.aggregate([
  { $group : {_id : "$field_1" } },
  { $out : "collection_group" }     ])
```

I've found how to do this in C++ in the MongoDB documentation. In this case it executes a sum after grouping, I want to insert the result in a new collection, but I supose I would only have to change "$sum" for "$out" :

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_1");
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$field_1" }, 
{ "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } });
```

The thing is that I can't find examples in vb .net. In vb .net, I've tried for example this to group:

```
Dim collection_act = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("collection_1")
collection_act.Group(New GroupArgs("_id", "$field_1"))
```

But it causes an error because the GroupArgs cannot be defined like this.

I tried to use the Aggregate method too, but I have the same problem defining the AggregateArgs, and I can't find how to define it.

The most interesting thing would be to create a pipeline and then add commands to it, because after doing this I have to remove documents based on these group.

Any help will be very appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean C#, not C++. Anyway, I know nothing about vb.net, but you likely should be calling `collection_act.Aggregate().Group` instead of `collection_act.Group`.

Comment: I've tried, but I can't call it like this in Vb.net